# Can I find the web hosting company from an IP address?

Tags: web-hosting, ip-address, whois, networking

If I have an IP address, is there a way to find the web hosting service that this IP address belongs to?

I tried using whois and traceroute but no luck so far.

The case is that my friend bought a domain and storage several years ago and he can't remember where he bought the storage from.

Comment: Why is the whois information not the one you are looking for ?

Comment: because for some reason  whois did not give me any information regarding the company.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try querying the ripe database
http://www.db.ripe.net/whois

Comment: That will pretty much always work.

Answer (score 7):

Or try http://www.whoishostingthis.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can also check on [robtex](http://www.robtex.com/) for a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

dnsstuff.com and do the free "IP information" tool, you'll be able to see the physical proximity of the IP. It will also give you rev dns, ans name, country, among other bits of information that would be helpful. Lots of clues to help you out.